# \center environment centers the whole document in LaTeX

Tags: latex

I have the following line between my \maketitle and my \begin{abstract}:

```
\center{ \textsc{Some text here} }
```

This seems to cause the ENTIRE DOCUMENT to be formatted as centered. Why is this and how should I get around it?

Comment: If you have two questions, ask two separate questions. Your two parts have nothing to do with each other.

Comment: Edited. Second questionhere: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2487252/

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Try

```
\begin{center}
    \textsc{Some text here} }  
 \end{center}
```

instead. `center` is an *environment*, meaning it needs to be used with `\begin`  and `\end`.

Furthermore there is the `\centering` command which turns on centered alignment for the rest of the block. I assume `\center` is a similar command from plain TeX.

Comment: `\begin{center}` expands to `\center`; `\end{center}` expands to `\endcenter`, so you’re not actually leaving latex with `\center`.

Comment: @deb: Ah, thanks for the clarification. Still, I believe, “environments” are meant to be used with `\begin` and `\end`, though so far I didn't know exactly what that translates to. The joy of layers upon layers upon laters of templates/macros. Wikipedia looks the same ;-)

Comment: Yeah, you should use them with `\begin{}` and `\end{}`, because that way, a new `\begingroup` will be started. But that’s just a minor detail, I guess…

Comment: It's pretty complicated (as is everything in LaTeX's internals) but the gist of it is that `\begin{center}` translates to `\begingroup\center` and `\end{center}` translates to `\endcenter\endgroup` in a "safe" way, i.e. it doesn't generate an error if `\endcenter` isn't defined (although if `\center` isn't defined then it will complain).  `\begingroup` and `endgroup` are scope operators, similar to `{` and `}` but without the ability to group arguments or box contents.  I.e. `\def\foo{bar}\begingroup\def\foo{baz}\endgroup\foo` will result in `bar`.

Comment: Ok ok, I think it was wise for me to stick to Word ;-)