# Making the draft document option in LaTeX have extra text appear in LaTeX

Tags: latex

Is there a way to get some text to appear only when the [draft] option is active.

For example, when the draft option is active, I want some text to appear between my title and abstract: "draft: do not cite without permission" or some such.

Comment: Memoir has a "ifdraftdoc" thing, but it doesn't work in article...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Usually this is done with

```
\usepackage{ifdraft}
\ifdraft{stern warning}{}
```

Where to put the `\ifdraft` depends on how you've created the layout of your title page.